# Setting the selected value on a Django forms.ChoiceField

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Here is the field declaration in a form:

```
max_number = forms.ChoiceField(widget = forms.Select(), 
    choices = ([('1','1'), ('2','2'),('3','3'), ]), initial='3', required = True,)
```

I would like to set the initial value to be `3` and this doesn't seem to work. I have played about with the param, quotes/no quotes, etc... but no change.

Could anyone give me a definitive answer if it is possible? And/or the necessary tweak in my code snippet?

*I am using Django 1.0*

Comment: I've been wondering the same thing. "initial" doesn't seam to work with choices in the latest trunk version as well.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Try setting the initial value when you instantiate the form:

```
form = MyForm(initial={'max_number': '3'})
```

Comment: Is ```'3'``` corresponding to the first value of the tuple or the second?

Comment: the tuples represent (value, label) pairs for the options and you want to specify the initial value - so the '3' refers to the first item.

Answer (score 119):

This doesn't touch on the immediate question at hand, but this Q/A comes up for searches related to trying to assign the selected value to a `ChoiceField`.

If you have already called `super().__init__` in your Form class, you should update the `form.initial` dictionary, not the `field.initial` property.  If you study `form.initial` (e.g. `print self.initial` after the call to `super().__init__`), it will contain values for *all* the fields.  Having a value of `None` in that dict will override the `field.initial` value.

e.g.

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # assign a (computed, I assume) default value to the choice field
        self.initial['choices_field_name'] = 'default value'
        # you should NOT do this:
        self.fields['choices_field_name'].initial = 'default value'
```

Comment: if you do not understand this answer, read this [django form gotchas](http://www.avilpage.com/2015/03/django-form-gotchas-dynamic-initial.html)

Comment: I am not sure if it is because this answer is so old that this no longer works, but I am unable to make this solution work.  I have tried every combination of the above and still I get no love.  I have asked this question again here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52191096/how-do-i-set-selected-on-choicefield-in-django-2-1-forms  If the answer is still the same, please let me know what is wrong with my code.  Thank you!

Answer (score 69):

You can also do the following. in your form class def:

```
max_number = forms.ChoiceField(widget = forms.Select(), 
                 choices = ([('1','1'), ('2','2'),('3','3'), ]), initial='3', required = True,)
```

then when calling the form in your view you can dynamically set both initial choices and choice list.

```
yourFormInstance = YourFormClass()

yourFormInstance.fields['max_number'].choices = [(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)]
yourFormInstance.fields['max_number'].initial = [1]
```

Note: the initial values has to be a list and the choices has to be 2-tuples, in my example above i have a list of 2-tuples. Hope this helps.

Comment: Perhaps worth noting that the value of `initial` refers to the key of the item to be selected, not its index. Took me a couple of tries to work this out!

Comment: This one seemed to work fine opposed to the other more upvoted answer.

Answer (score 22):

I ran into this problem as well, and figured out that the problem is in the browser. When you refresh the browser is re-populating the form with the same values as before, ignoring the checked field. If you view source, you'll see the checked value is correct. Or put your cursor in your browser's URL field and hit enter. That will re-load the form from scratch.

Comment: just fyi, This still happen in FF6. Pressing the refresh button is not enough. But in google chrome refresh button is enough, no need to go to address bar

Comment: I think it will always happen in Firefox; it's intended behaviour.

Answer (score 11):

Both Tom and Burton's answers work for me eventually, but I had a little trouble figuring out how to apply them to a [`ModelChoiceField`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField).

The only trick to it is that the choices are stored as tuples of `(<model's ID>, <model's unicode repr>)`, so if you want to set the initial model selection, you pass the model's **ID** as the initial value, not the object itself or it's name or anything else. Then it's as simple as:

```
form = EmployeeForm(initial={'manager': manager_employee_id})
```

Alternatively the `initial` argument can be ignored in place of an extra line with:

```
form.fields['manager'].initial = manager_employee_id
```

Comment: Your second line of code works flawlessly in one of those rare cases where you need to set a form's initial value after a `GET` request and set it from within a view.

Comment: I confirm, that's the only way to make it work using `ModelChoiceField` (Django 2.1, sadly. Maybe in newer ones it works better).

Answer (score 3):

Dave - any luck finding a solution to the browser problem?  Is there a way to force a refresh?

As for the original problem, try the following when initializing the form:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
  super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)   
  self.base_fields['MyChoiceField'].initial = initial_value
```

Comment: This doesn't look nicely. Quoted from django 1.3, forms.py:93:
`Instances should always modify self.fields; they should not modify self.base_fields.`

Answer (score 2):

*Note: This answer is quite comprehensive and focuses on both static and dynamic initial values as this Q/A comes up for searches related to dynamic changing of initial value, and I believe that the information below will be of great use to junior programmers.*

### How to set the initial value

There are **multiple options how to set the initial value** of a `ChoiceField` (or any other field, e.g. `DecimalField`). The various options can be

- **static** (i.e. initial value doesn't change),
- **form-dynamic** (i.e. initial value can be calculated/changed in the form constructor in `forms.py`),
- **view-dynamic** (i.e. initial value can be calculated/changed in the `view.py`).

All of the options presented below **can be combined**, but beware of the [initial value precedences](https://avilpage.com/2015/03/django-form-gotchas-dynamic-initial.html)!

##### Option A - Static initial value defined in the class

You can set the initial value right in the definition of the field in the form class. This option is only static.

In `forms.py`:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
     max_number = forms.ChoiceField(initial='3')
```

##### Option B - Initial value defined in instance constructor

You can set the initial value when creating a form instance. This option can be static or form-dynamic.

In `forms.py`:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    max_number = forms.ChoiceField()
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.initial['max_number'] = '3'
```

You could also use `self.fields['max_number'].initial = '3'` instead of `self.initial['max_number'] = '3'` but this is [not recommened](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11400559/11875147) unless you want the [initial value to be overridable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76184715/11875147).

##### Option C - Initial value in the form call

You can set the initial value in the arguments of the form call. This option can be static or view-dynamic.

In `views.py`:

```
my_form = MyForm(initial={'max_number': '3'})
```

##### Option D - Initial value using keyword arguments

You can also send the initial value as a keyword argument (kwarg) to the form constructor, and then use this kwarg as the initial value. This option can be static, form-dynamic or view-dynamic.

In `views.py`:

```
my_form = MyForm(my_init_kwarg=3)
```

In `forms.py`:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    max_number = forms.ChoiceField()
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'my_init_kwarg' in kwargs:
            init_val = kwargs.pop('my_init_kwarg')
        else:
            init_val = 1  # fallback value if kwarg is not provided
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.initial['max_number'] = init_val
```

*Note: Lines 4 to 7 can be simplified to `init_val = kwargs.pop('my_init_kwarg', 1)`*

##### Option E - Create bound form

You can create the form as a bound form and pass the initial value as the data for the bound form. This option can be static or view-dynamic.

In `views.py`:

```
form_data = {'max_number':3}
my_form = MyForm(form_data)
```

In `forms.py`:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    max_number = forms.ChoiceField()
```

For more about bound and unbound forms see [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/api/#bound-and-unbound-forms).

### Additional notes specific for ChoiceFields

Note that the **initial value refers to the key** of the item to be selected, not its index nor display text - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5132462/11875147). So, if you had this list of choices

```
choices = ([('3','three'), ('2','two'), ('1','one')])
```

and wanted to set `one` as the initial value, you would use

```
max_number = forms.ChoiceField(initial='1')
```

Answer (score 1):

To be sure I need to see how you're rendering the form. The initial value is only used in a unbound form, if it's bound and a value for that field is not included nothing will be selected.