# Django Model form with a hidden field won't pass validation

Tags: django, django-forms

When I have a field which is hidden but specified in the modelform, it fails to pass validation. The below form fails to pass validation for the postcode field, even though I pass in the postcode data in the constructor. How do I attach data to it to pass validation correctly so that it can save?

eg

```
class SupplyAddressForm(forms.ModelForm):
    full_address = forms.ChoiceField()

    def __init__(self, postcode, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        raw_addresses_data = get_full_address(postcode)
        addresses = raw_addresses_data['data']['addresses']
        ...........
        self.fields['postcode'].initial = postcode



    def save(self, commit=False):
        address = super().save(commit=False)
        cd = self.cleaned_data
        full_address = cd['full_address']
        full_address = json.loads(full_address)
        ......
        return address

    class Meta:
        model = Address
        fields = [
            'supply_months',
            'supply_years',
            'postcode',
            'residential_status',
        ]

        widgets = {
             'postcode': forms.HiddenInput
        }
```

Comment: Initial data is not used to fill gaps in provided data.

Comment: On the rendered form, does the `postcode` field have a value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this [documentaion](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/fields/#initial) to understand why Initial is not suitable for your puposes.

Instead, override the 'is_valid' method.
In 'is_valid', change the value of the hidden field AFTER the form is submitted. I got this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/813418/django-set-field-value-after-a-form-is-initialized)

Comment: Thanks I stupidly didn't include my clean method here which is where the issue was.