# How do I programmatically set fields in ModelForm in Django?

Tags: python, django-forms

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642625/how-do-i-initiate-values-for-fields-in-a-form-for-editing-in-a-template) I want to convert my form from regular `Form` to `ModelForm` so I can take advantage of `instance` parameter in `ModelForm`.

Here is my current form code:

```
class OrderDetailForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(
        self,
        user,
        can_edit_work_type=None,
        can_edit_vendor=None,
        can_edit_note=None,
        *args,
        **kwargs
    ):
        super(OrderDetailForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if can_edit_work_type:
            self.fields['work_type'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=Order.WORK_TYPE_CHOICES)
        if can_edit_vendor:
            self.fields['vendor'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(
                queryset=Vendor.objects.all(),
                empty_label="Choose a vendor",
            )
        if can_edit_note:
            self.fields['note'] = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

    def clean(self):
        super(OrderDetailForm, self).clean()

        if 'note' in self.cleaned_data:
            if len(self.cleaned_data['note']) < 50:
                self._errors['note'] = self.error_class([u"Please enter a longer note."])

                del self.cleaned_data['note']

        return self.cleaned_data
```

As you can see, I have some `if` statements that determine whether the fields even show you in the forms (logically it means certain users can only edit certain parts of the fields).

How would I do that in `ModelForm`? I understand `fields` to be a tuple, so it can't be appended like I did in `Form`. So I want to do something like

```
class OrderDetailForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        # fields = ('work_type', 'vendor', 'note') I can't do that since I need to be able to control it. See below.

        # Can I control widgets even if that field doesn't exist?
        widgets = {
            'note': forms.Textarea(),
        }

    def __init__(
        self,
        user,
        can_edit_work_type=None,
        can_edit_vendor=None,
        can_edit_note=None,
        *args,
        **kwargs
    ):
        super(OrderDetailForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        fields = []

        if can_edit_work_type:
            fields.append('work_type')
        if can_edit_vendor:
            fields.append('vendor')
        if can_edit_note:
            fields.append('note')

        self.Meta.fields = tuple(fields) # Does this work?

    def clean(self):
        super(OrderDetailForm, self).clean()

        if 'note' in self.cleaned_data:
            if len(self.cleaned_data['note']) < 50:
                self._errors['note'] = self.error_class([u"Please enter a longer note."])

                del self.cleaned_data['note']

        return self.cleaned_data
```

Is that possible? How do you control the fields in `ModelForm`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another possible way is generate a inline form class in the view to exclude fields based on the request, for example, define a normal model form for Order model, called OrderDetailForm:

```
class OrderDetailForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ('work_type', 'vendor', 'note') 
        widgets = {
            'note': forms.Textarea(),
        }
```

In the view, for example, edit order, create a customized form based on the OrderDetailForm:

```
def edit(request, order_id):
    order = Order.objects.get(pk=order_id)
    can_edit_work_type = bool(request.REQUEST.get('can_edit_work_type', False))
    can_edit_vender = bool(request.REQUEST.get('can_edit_vender', False))
    can_edit_note = bool(request.REQUEST.get('can_edit_note', False))

    exclude_fields = []

    if not can_edit_work_type:
        exclude_fields.append('work_type')

    if not can_edit_vender:
        exclude_fields.append('vender')

    if not can_edit_note:
        exclude_fields.append('note')

    class CustomizedOrderForm(OrderDetailForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Order
            exclude = tuple(exclude_fields)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomizedOrderForm(instance=order, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        form = CustomizedOrderForm(instance=order)
    return render(request, 'order_form.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: I like to keep my request handlers as to the point as possible and put the logic in `forms`, `models` and elsewhere rather than in the handler itself.

Comment: This doesn't return a HttpResponse upon valid post.

Comment: This does not add fields to the form. ... or does it ... hmm ... it's kinda' brilliant, but the nested class in the handler is just plain wrong ;)

Comment: Well I'm not sure about controlling the fields via `GET`, but I do like the idea of excluding fields one by one.

Answer (score 2):

The `ModelForm` api is very similar to that of the regular `Form`.  The advantage is that you now get [model validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects) in addition to conveniences like default widgets, the instance kwarg, and the save method.

`fields` `attr` is still `dict`-like. You can see fields getting built by the metaclass [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py#L186). Then, going [through](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py#L368) the [inheritance](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py#L225) and calling `super()` in the `BaseModelForm.__init__`, we arrive at a `deepcopy` of the [declared fields](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/forms.py#L95), [originally](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/forms.py#L29) a `SortedDict`. This is common to `Form` and `ModelForm`, both subclasses of `BaseForm`.

Put the fields in the [exclude](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-a-subset-of-fields-on-the-form) and add them the way you are doing in the original `__init__`.

Clean them the same way.

Then, you can override the `save` method: you can call `super()` to get the object back and deal with the data in `cleaned_data` however you want.

```
class OrderDetailForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # regular fields, not based on bools
    # ...

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        exclude = ('work_type', 'vendor', 'note')
        # or fields = (...other fields )


    def __init__(
        self,
        user,
        can_edit_work_type=None,
        can_edit_vendor=None,
        can_edit_note=None,
        *args,
        **kwargs,
    ):
        super(OrderDetailForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if can_edit_work_type:
            self.fields['work_type'] = forms.ChoiceField(
                                       choices=Order.WORK_TYPE_CHOICES)
        if can_edit_vendor:
            self.fields['vendor'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(
                queryset=Vendor.objects.all(),
                empty_label="Choose a vendor",
            )
        if can_edit_note:
            self.fields['note'] = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

    def clean(self):
        # I never call super() in clean .. do I? .. hmmm
        # maybe I should or is sth magic going on?
        # alternately,
        # data = self.cleaned_data
        # let's call super though
        data = super(OrderDetailForm, self).clean()

        if 'note' in data:
            if len(data['note']) < 50:
                # I raise a validation error so .is_valid() comes back False
                # form.errors happens magically ...
                raise forms.ValidationError("Not long enough ...")

        return data

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        data = self.cleaned_data
        # maybe do some stuff here
        # ...

        # commit=True or commit=False could be important
        order = super(OrderDetailForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        if 'note' in data:
            order.note = data['note']

        # ... do other stuff

        # probably ...
        order.save()

        # respect how model forms work.
        return order
```

Comment: So how do just I add a model field to `fields` under `__init__`? Can I just do something like `self.fields.append('note')`? It seems like `fields` is still a tuple, not a dictionary.

Comment: In the regular `Form`, you aren't appending to the fields attr but rather assigning values to its keys.