# how do I set values of CheckBoxes in Django

Tags: django, django-forms

I want to set the values of a checkbox(BooleanField) in Django-forms. The values are the name of the users, hence variable. So, setting default value isn't an option.

**Forms.py**

```
class UserForm(forms.Form):
   user    = forms.BooleanField()        // value set should be of the name of user
```

**Template.html**

```
{% for user in users %}
  {{user_form.as_table}} {{user.name}}
{%endfor%}
```

**Views.py**

```
users = GrabhaloUser.objects.all()
user_form = UserForm(request.POST or None)
if request.method == 'POST':
        if(user_form.is_valid()):
            selected_users = user_form.cleaned_data['user']
            #get_data(request,selected_users,query)     //this is some function. Ignore this.

ctx = {
            'users' : users,
            'user_form' : user_form
    }

return render_to_response('dashboard/dashboard.html',ctx, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You should probably rethink your approach. What does the `user` field in your form mean, and how would you want to select users with it? Most likely a [ChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield) is more applicable. For details about this field, see for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657607/setting-the-selected-value-on-a-django-forms-choicefield).

Otherwise, rename your field to make it more descriptive, e.g. `selected`. In this case, you will have to distinguish between users, which in turn means you will have to prefix your form identifiers and names. In other words, build your form manually. As an example (adjust to your specific needs)

```
{% for user in users %}
  <input id="user_pk_{{ user.pk }}" value="{{ user.pk }}" type="hidden" />
  <input id="user_selected_{{ user.pk }}" type="checkbox"{% if user.selected %} checked="checked"{% endif %} />
  <input id="user_some_property_{{ user.pk }}" type="text" value="{{ user.some_property }}" />
{% endfor %}
```

Then finally, in your view, get all your entries and process them. Again, for example:

```
keys = [k for k in user_form.cleaned_data.keys() if k.startswith('user_pk_')]
pks = [pk..rsplit('_', 1)[-1] for pk in keys]
for pk in pks:
    user = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
    user.selected = user_form.cleaned_data['user_selected_'+pk]
    # Et cetera
```