# How to dynamically update the 'initial' value in a Form ChoiceField

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a Form with the following field:

```
image_choices = [] 
images = forms.ChoiceField(label=_("Images"), choices=image_choices, initial="")
```

I need to be able to update the value of the 'initial' attribute, after I learn what that value should be. 
Currently, I have this assignment done within the `__init__`:

```
def __init__(self, request, image_choices=image_choices,
             flavor_choices=flavor_choices, args, *kwargs): 
    super(UpdateWorkload, self).__init__(request, args, *kwargs) 
    selected_image = selected_workload['image'] 
    self.fields['images'].initial = selected_image
```

I do not get any errors, and, when printed, the value is there,
 but, in the actual form on the screen, 
I still get my default list, and no specific items are selected, as per `self.fields['images'].initial = str(selected_image)`

How can I fix that?

Comment: Did you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11400559 ?

Comment: FWIW, dynamic initial values have been a thing since Django 2.0: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values

Answer (score 5):

After all, using this approach:

```
self.fields['images'].initial = selected_image
self.fields['flavors'].initial = selected_flavor
```

is working. The only thing I did differently was changing my backend from django restframework to tastypie

Answer (score 0):

**DANGEROUS SOLUTION:**

While the [Eugene Goldberg's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28132326/11875147) solution

```
self.fields['images'].initial = selected_image
```

does work, it may not be safe in certain scenarios.

The problem with this solution is that you are setting an initial value for a FORM field. This means that this value **can be overriden** if some other initial values for the FORM are specified in the arguments of the created form (see [Colinta's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11400559/11875147)), e.g.:

```
images = forms.ChoiceField(label=_("Images"), choices=image_choices, initial={'images': some_other_image})
```

*Note: Of course, if this behaviour is desirable in your specific app (i.e. sometimes you want to override the initial value defined in `__init__`). This "dangerous" solution is right for you.*

**BETTER SOLUTION:**

If you want to define an initial value for the field which **cannot be overridden** by the initial values of the form, you must set the initial value of the FIELD (see [Avil Page blog](https://avilpage.com/2015/03/django-form-gotchas-dynamic-initial.html) and [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values))

```
self.initial['images'] = selected_image
```

**OTHER SOLUTIONS:**

For other solutions how to dynamically change initial values, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76202007/11875147).