# Preselect a set of choices in CheckboxSelectMultiple

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a MultipleChoiceField form field that contains dynamic choices. I would like to preselect a (dynamic) set of these while the rest should remain unchecked. Is there some way to do this?

```
widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={'checked': 'checked'})
```

Will cause all choices to be checked, however i only need some to be checked.

Help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting the selected value on a Django forms.ChoiceField](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/657607/setting-the-selected-value-on-a-django-forms-choicefield)

Answer (score 0):

You have to these choices as the field's initial. For example:

```
    my_field = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
         widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
         choices=(('foo', 'Foo text'), ('bar', 'Bar text'), ('baz', 'Baz text')),
         initial=('foo', 'bar'))
    )
```

If you want these values to be dynamic, you must change the initial parameter for your field at any step before rendering the form. This can be achieved like this:

```
    my_dynamic_initials = ('foo', 'bar')
    my_form.fields['my_field'].initial = my_dynamic_initials
```

Comment: Neither of these worked for me.  I pasted your code exactly into my project and none of the choices were selected.  Not when I hard coded the options into the form definition and not when I added them dynamically via __init__.

Comment: Apparently you need to use my_form.initial['my_field'] = my_dynamic_initials NOT my_form.fields['my_field'] = my_dynamic_initials.  I still never got the passing of the initial=('foo','bar') as key word arguments working.