# Initial value in form's __init__ for the model with generic relation

Tags: python, django

I have a model with generic relation like this:

```
  content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

  object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

  content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

To make the life easier for the user I have modified the form. The idea was to have one field with choices instead of multiple. For that I have merged fields into choices inside of form's init().

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(AdminTaskForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    # combine object_type and object_id into a single 'generic_obj' field
    # getall the objects that we want the user to be able to choose from
    available_objects = list(Event.objects.all())
    available_objects += list(Contest.objects.all())

    # now create our list of choices for the <select> field
    object_choices = []
    for obj in available_objects:
        type_id = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(obj.__class__).id
        obj_id = obj.id
        form_value = "type:%s-id:%s" % (type_id, obj_id)  # e.g."type:12-id:3"
        display_text = str(obj)
        object_choices.append([form_value, display_text])
    self.fields['content_object'].choices = object_choices
```

Till now everything was working fine, but now I have to provide initial value for content_object field.

I have added this code to init() but it is not working:

```
    initial = kwargs.get('initial')
    if initial:
        if initial['content_object']:
            object = initial['content_object']
            object_id = object.id
            object_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(object).id
            form_value = "type:%s-id:%s" % (object_type, object_id)
            self.fields['content_object'].initial = form_value
```

Any suggestions why I cannot set initial value inside of init? Thanks!

P.S. Debug output looks for me ok, but initial is not set at all.

```
print(self.fields['content_object'].choices) --> [['type:32-id:10050', 'Value1'], ['type:32-id:10056', 'Value2']]
print(form_value) --> type:32-id:10056
```

Answer (score 2):

I have found a nice answer to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11400559/709897):

> If you have already called super().**init** in your Form class, you
>   should update the form.initial dictionary, not the field.initial
>   property. If you study form.initial (e.g. print self.initial after the
>   call to super().**init**), it will contain values for all the fields.
>   Having a value of None in that dict will override the field.initial
>   value

The solution to the problem was then just adding one additional line:

```
self.initial['content_object'] = form_value
```