# Set radio button initial value if choices come from queryset

Tags: django, forms, radio-button

I have a form set up as follows. Form class has radio group:

```
class BookForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        widgets = {
            'book_type': RadioSelect(attrs={'class': 'horizontal-radiogroup'}),
        }
```

And in init, the choices are set dynamically:

```
self.fields['book_type'].queryset = available_book_types
```

Where `available_book_types` is a queryset that is filtered based on conditions.

I need to dynamically set a value in the radio group as checked in the template.

I tried the following:

```
self.fields['book_type'].initial = available_book_types.filter(category='Fiction').first()
```

But it didn't work. Is there a way to achieve this, or do I need to handle this with JavaScript in the frontend?

Edit:
I use the form as follows:

Called from view:

```
def book_get_response(request, book=None)
    ...
    initial_data = request.GET
    form = BookForm(instance=book, initial=initial_data)
    return {'form': form}
```

In init I have the code I originally posted.

I have actually managed to get it working if I set it before creating form, in the `initial_data`dict. It works if I set the the book:

```
initial_data['book_type'] = Book.objects.filter(category='Fiction').first()
```

However, if I print the `initial`of the field in **init**, it shows up as None, yet the radio button is checked correctly in the template. Why is this?

Comment: Are you sure the `available_book_types` *has* an item with `category='Fiction'`? If not, `.first()` will return `None`, and then no initial one is picked.

Comment: Can you furthermore share *how* you are using the form in the view?

Comment: I'm sure it exits. I updated the original question now with some details. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. Apparently, the issue was that I tried setting the initial value after calling `super`. Before this the `fields` attribute is not accesable, so the solution was to use

`self.initial['book_type'] = Book.objects.filter(category='Fiction').first()`

Also discussed here:
[Initial value in form's __init__ for the model with generic relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39758386/initial-value-in-forms-init-for-the-model-with-generic-relation)