# How to pre select value in a django forms.Select field

Tags: html, django, python-3.x

I am new to django. I am creating a simple CRUD application using django 2.2, I have a simple addstudent.html page where i can add data in some fields including a dropdown where I can select the class of student and database is updated. Below is my code:
forms.py

```
class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class_list= [
    ('Class IIX', 'Class IIX'),
    ('Class IX', 'Class IX'),
    ('Class X', 'Class X'),
    ('Class XI', 'Class XI'),
    ('Class XII', 'Class XII')
    ]
    student_class= forms.CharField(label='Class', widget=forms.Select(choices=class_list,attrs={'style': 'width:175px'}))
    class Meta:
        model=Student
        fields='__all__'
```

models.py

```
class Student(models.Model):
    student_id=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    student_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    student_email=models.EmailField()
    student_contact=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    student_class=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    class Meta:
        db_table='student'
```

snippet of addstudent.html template where dropdown is shown correctly

```html
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="sname" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Student Class:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        {{form.student_class}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Problem: I am not able to figure out how to preselect the dropdown when I edit a student, I get the value as 'Class X' from the database but how do i use this database value to select correct option in dropdown?

Please Note: This project is for school kids and I can't use JQUERY/JAVASCRIPT here.

Comment: Are you using django's class-based `UpdateView` for **editing** student info? Show us your view code.

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657607/setting-the-selected-value-on-a-django-forms-choicefield/1833636

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem probably is not related to initial. Django handles this automatically when you instantiate the form correctly. You need to pass the student instance through the constructor within your view.

```
StudentForm(instance=student_object)
```