# How can I get an option selected by default in a forms.ChoiceField in Django?

Tags: django, forms

I have something like this:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):

    CHOICES = (
        ('opt1', 'Opt1'),
        ('group',(
            ('opt2', 'Opt2'),
            ('opt3', 'Opt3'),
            )
        ),
    )   
    
    myfield = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, required=False)
```

when i render this form, opt1 is selected by default, But I need opt3 to be the selected one.

i tried something like:

```
myfield = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, required=False, initial="opt3")
```

but it didnt work.

what i get:

```
<select name="myfield" id="id_myfield">
    <option value="opt1">Opt1</option>
    <optgroup label="group">
        <option value="opt2">Opt2</option>
        <option value="opt3">Opt3</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

what im trying to get:

```
<select name="myfield" id="id_myfield">
    <option value="opt1">Opt1</option>
    <optgroup label="group">
        <option value="opt2">Opt2</option>
        <option value="opt3" selected>Opt3</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

How can i get opt3 selected by default?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657607/setting-the-selected-value-on-a-django-forms-choicefield this should work

Comment: Now it work, it didnt work before because in my view i had MyForm(request.GET)
to complete with the data filled by the user. Then the initial data is ignored.
I made it work with an if sentence asking for request.GET, then MyForm(request.GET) or MyForm() according to the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its work

```
myfield = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, required=False, initial="opt3`")
```

my problem was my view:

```
form = MyForm(request.GET)
```

now i solve the problem with:

```
if request.GET:
    form = MyForm(request.GET)
else:
    form = MyForm()
```